# What is the personality of indra in vedas?

Tags: vedas, indra

In the Puranas Indra is depicted as a bad king of heaven. And sometimes wrathful . But how is he depicted in vedas.

I mean what is his personality?

---

<sup>There is a story in bhagavad puran. krishna ordered people to worship goverdhan pervat(mountain). But on that day people used to celebrate a festival for lord Indra. No one worshiped indra, he got angry and Punished them by giving them rainstorm.</sup>

Comment: Indra has his flaws but he is a great defender of Hinduism and devotee of Vishnu.

Comment: Indra is supreme in Rig Veda but the Puranas denigrated him as a person of low morals.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A nice summary of Indra from

[SOURCE](https://archive.org/stream/vedicreaderforst00macd/VEDICREADERFORST00MACD_DJVU.TXT)

> INDRA

> Indra is invoked alone in about one-fourth of the hymns of the RV., far
> more than are addressed to any other deity ; for he is the favourite national
> god of the Vedic people. He is more anthropomorphic on the physical side,
> and more invested with mythological imagery, than any other member of the
> pantheon. He is primarily a god of the thunderstorm who vanquishes the
> demons of drought or darkness, and sets free the vsraters or wins the light.
> He is secondarily the god of battle who aids the victorious Aryan in over-
> coming his aboriginal foes.

> His physical features, such as body and head, are often referred to ;
> after he has drunk Soma he agitates his jaws and his beard ; and his belly
> is many times mentioned in connexion with his great powers of drinking
> Soma. Being tawny (hari) in colour, he is also tawny-haired and tawny-
> bearded. His arms are especially often referred to because they wield the

> 42 INDEA [ii. 12

> thunderbolt (vajra), which, mythologically representing the lightning
> stroke, is his exclusive weapon. This bolt was fashioned for him by Tvastr,
> being made of iron (ayasa), golden, tawny, sharp, many-pointed, sometimes
> spoken of as a stone or rock. Several epithets, compounds or derivatives
> of vajra, such as vajra-bahu bearing the holt m his arm and vajrin tvielder
> of the holt are almost without exception applied to him. Sometimes he is
> described as armed with bow and arrows ; he also carries a hook (afikusa).

> Having a golden car, drawn by two tawny steeds (hari), he is a car-
> fighter (rathestha). Both his car and his steeds were fashioned by the
> Rbhus, the divine artificers.

> As Indra is more addicted to Soma than any of the other gods, the
> comm(?n epithet ' Soma-drinker ' (Somapa) is characteristic of him. This
> beverage stimulates him to carry out his warlike deeds; thus for the
> slaughter of Vrtra he is said to have drunk three lakes of Soma. One whole
> hymn (x. 119) is a monologue in which Indra, intoxicated with Soma, boasts
> of his greatness and his might.

> Indra is often spoken of as having been born, and two whole hymns
> deal with the subject of his birth. His father, the same as Agni's, appears
> to be Dyaus ; but the inference from other passages is that he is Tvastr, the
> artificer among the gods. Agni is called Indra's twin brother, and Pusan
> (vi. 54) is also his brother. His wife, who is often mentioned, is Indranl.
> Indra is associated with various other deities. The Maruts (i. 85) are his
> chief allies, who constantly help him in his conflicts. Hence the epithet
> Marutvant accompanied hy the Maruts is characteristic of him. Agni is
> the god most often conjoined with him as a dual divinity. Indra is also
> often coupled with Varuna (vii. 86) and Vayu, god of Wind, less often with
> Soma (viii. 48), Brhaspati (iv. 50), Pusan, and Visnu.

> Indra is of vast size ; thus it is said that he would be equal to the earth
> even if it were ten times as large as it is. His greatness and power are
> constantly dwelt on : neither gods nor men have attained to the limit of
> his might ; and no one like him is known among the gods. Thus various
> epithets such as sakra and sacivant mighty, sacipati lord of might, sata-
> kratu having a hundred potvers, are characteristic of him.

> The essential myth forming the basis of his nature is described with
> extreme frequency and much variation. Exhilarated by Soma and generally
> escorted by the Maruts, he attacks the chief demon of drought, usually
> called Vrtra, but often also the serpent (ahi). Heaven and Earth tremble
> when the mighty combat takes place. With his bolt he shatters Vrtra
> who encompasses the waters, hence receiving the exclusive epithet apsu-jit
> conquering in the tvaters- The result of the conflict, which is regarded as
> being constantly renewed, is that he pierces the mountain and sets free
> the waters pent up like imprisoned cows. The physical elements in the
> conflict are nearly always the bolt, the mountain, waters or rivers, while

> ii. 12] INDRA 43

> lightning, thunder, cloud, rain are seldom directly named. The waters are
> often terrestrial, but also often aerial and celestial. The clouds are the
> mountains (parvata, giri), on which the demons lie or dwell, or from which
> Indra casts them down, or which he cleaves to release the waters. Or the
> cloud is a rock (adri) which encompasses the cows (as the waters are
> f; sometimes called), and from which he releases them. Clouds, as containing
> the waters, figure as cows also; they further appear under the names of
> udder (iidhar), spring (litsa), cask (kavandha), pail (ko^a). The clouds,
> moreover, appear as the fortresses (puras) of the aerial demons, being
> described as moving, autumnal, made of iron or stone, and as 90, 99, or
> 100 in number. Indra shatters them and is characteristically called the
> 'fort-destroyer' (purbhid). But the chief and specific epithet of Indra is
> ' Vrtra-slayer ' (Vrtra-han), owing to the essential importance, in the myth,
> of the fight with the demon. In this fight the Maruts are his regular
> allies, but Agni, Soma, and Visnu also often assist him. Indra also engages
> in conflict with numerous minor demons ; sometimes he is described as
> destroying demons in general, the Raksases or the Asuras.

> With the release of the waters is connected the winning of light, sun,
> and dawn. Thus Indra is invoked to slay Vrtra and to win the light.
> When he had slain Vrtra, releasing the waters for man, he placed the
> sun visibly in the heavens. The sun shone forth when Indra blew the
> serpent from the air. There is here often no reference to the Vrtra fight.
> Indra is then simply said to find the light ; he gained the sun or found it
> in the darkness, and made a path for it. He produces the dawn as well as
> the sun ; he opens the darkness with the dawn and the sun. The cows
> mentioned along with the sun and dawn, or with the sun alone, as found,
> released, or won by Indra, are here probably the morning beams, which are
> elsewhere compared with cattle coming out of their dark stalls. Thus when
> the dawns went to meet Indra, he became the lord of the cows ; when he
> overcame Vrtra he made visible the cows of the nights. There seems to be
> a confusion between the restoration of the sun after the darkness of the
> thunderstorm, and the recovery of the sun from the darkness of night at
> dawn. The latter feature is probably an extension of the former. Indra's
> connexion with the thunderstorm is in a few passages divested of mytho-
> logical imagery, as when he is said to have created the lightnings of heaven
> and to have directed the action of the waters downwards. With the
> Vrtra-fight, with the winning of the cows and of the sun, is also connected
> the gaining of Soma. Thus when Indra drove the serpent from the air,
> there shone forth fires, the sun, and Soma ; he won Soma at the same time
> as the cows.

> Great cosmic actions are often attributed to Indra. He settled the
> quaking mountains and plains. He stretches out heaven and earth like
> a hide ; he holds asunder heaven and earth as two wheels are kept apart by

> 44 INDRA [ii. 12

> the axle ; he made the non-existent into the existent in a moment. Some-
> times the separation and support of heaven and earth are described as
> a result of Indra's victory over a demon who held them together.

> As the destroyer of demons in combat, Indra is constantly invoked by
> warriors. As the great god of battle he is more frequently called upon than
> any other deity to help the Aryans in their conflicts with earthly enemies.
> He protects the Aryan colour and subjects the black skin. He dispersed
> 50,000 of the black race. He subjected the Dasyus to the Aryan, and gave
> land to the Aryan.

> More generally Indra is praised as the protector, helper, and friend of his
> worshippers. He is described as bestowing on them wealth, which is con-
> sidered the result of victories. His liberality is so characteristic that the
> frequent attribute maghavan bountiful is almost exclusively his.

> Besides the central myth of the Vrtra-fight, several minor stories are
> connected with Indra. In various passages he is described as shattering the
> car of Usas, goddess of Dawn (iv. 51); this trait is probably based on the
> notion of Indra's bringing the sun when kept back by the delaying dawn.
> He is also said to have stopped the steeds of the Sun, apparently by
> causing the latter to lose a wheel of his car. Indra is further associated
> with the myth of the winning of Soma ; for it is to him that the eagle brings
> the draught of immortality from the highest heaven. Another myth is
> the capture by Indra, with the help of Sarama, of the cows confined in
> a cave by demons called Panis.

> Various stories which, though mixed with mythological elements, pro-
> bably have an historical basis, are told of Indra's having fought in aid of
> individual proteges, such as king Sudas, against terrestrial foes.

> The attributes of Indra are chiefly those of physical superiority and rule
> over the physical world. He is energetic and violent in action, an
> irresistible fighter, an inexhaustible lavisher of the highest goods on man-
> kind, but at the same time sensual and immoral in various ways, such as
> excess in eating and drinking, and cruelty in killing his own father Tvastr.
> He forms a marked contrast to Varuna, the other great universal monarch of
> the RV., who wields passive and peaceful sway, who uniformly applies the
> laws of nature, who upholds moral order, and whose character displays lofty
> ethical features.

RigVeda X 119 (Brererton and Jamison translation) - Indra boasting about his Soma-drinking (Agni speaks the last verse)

> 1. Yes for sure! Yes (says) my mind: I could win cow and horse—yes! – Have I drunk of the soma? Yes!
> 2. Forth like raging winds, the draughts have lifted me up. – Have I drunk of the soma? Yes!
> 3. The draughts have lifted me up, like swift horses a chariot. – Have I drunk of the soma? Yes!
> 4. A thought has come up close to me, like a bellowing cow to her dear son. – Have I drunk of the soma? Yes!
> 5. Like an artisan a chariot-box, I bend the thought around with my heart. – Have I drunk of the soma? Yes!
> 6. Because the ﬁve peoples have not appeared to me to be even a speck . . . – Have I drunk of the soma? Yes!
> 7. Because both world-halves are not equal to even one wing of mine . . . – Have I drunk of the soma? Yes!
> 8. By my greatness I have surmounted heaven and this great earth. – Have I drunk of the soma? Yes!
> 9. Blast it! I will set down this earth here—or over here. – Have I drunk of the soma? Yes!
> 10. I will keep smiting the earth to blazes—here or over there. – Have I drunk of the soma? Yes!
> 11. In heaven is one wing of mine; I have dragged the other below. – Have I drunk of the soma? Yes!
> 12. Here I am—greater than great, sped upward to the clouds. – Have I drunk of the soma? Yes!
> 13. As a household that is properly equipped, I journey as the carrier of the oblations to the gods. – Have I drunk of the soma? Yes!

Comment: *"One whole hymn (x. 119) is a monologue in which Indra, intoxicated with Soma, boasts of his greatness and his might."* can you give the hymn

Comment: Thanks for the answer

Comment: Thanks for the edit.